# How can I create branching scripts that a caller can use as part of a membership signup workflow, etc?

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, user, workflow, user-interface

We're on Drupal and Civi 4.6.16.

I want to create forms with branching scripts for staff to use when doing membership signup calls, fundraising asks, etc.

I've created a webform using webform-civicrm that a caller signs into, with the contact and donor history info for the "target" contact, a "script" for the caller to use (using textarea fields), info on Activities to be created as appropriate based on the target's responses (like non-membership contribution ask - a one-on-one follow up meeting if the target agrees to meet).

But rather than have one long webform with various script options, I want to have the answers to questions asked in the script take the caller to a next step in that "workflow"- so if the target wants to contribute but does not want to schedule a follow up one-on-one meeting, then the script skips right to a page for the caller to get the target's contribution info while on the phone with the target.

However, if the target does agree to a one-on-one, then the script skips/branches to a page to create a non-membership ask activity/one-on-one meeting.

So have you done this? Are there public pages with examples?

Thanks for any info.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't explored this but my first thought is that conditional fields might be an option in webforms.

Based on whether the user checks this box or that box additional fields could appear. I think webform even supports doing multi-page forms and might be able to add those using this method.

Comment: Agree. Conditional fields is exactly how you can address this requirement.